# Ошибка перевода из 2 в 16 систему счисления

Tags: ассемблер, конвертация, dos

Здравствуйте, пишу программу на ассемблере, которая кодирует(конвертирует) двоичное число в двузначное шестнадцатеричное число. Написал данный код:

```
.model small
.data    
HEXDIGIT   DB  "0123456789ABCDEF"
VAR1 DB 10011001b

.stack 256 
.code      
main:      
mov ax, @data  
mov ds, ax  
MOV  AL , VAR1
MOV  BX , OFFSET  HEXDIGIT
XLAT
MOV  DL , AL
MOV AH , 02H
INT  21H

mov ax,4c00h
 int 21h    
 end main
```

Но терплю фиаско:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы берете все число в качестве смещения, а оно заведомо может больше 16. Вам надо взять сначала старшие 4 бита числа (`shr al,4`) - получите xlat первый символ, потом в al возвращаете исходное число и оставляете от него младшие 4 бита (`and al,0Fh`) и получаете второй символ

Comment: @Mike фух, чуток повозился и заработало. Очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Благодарю пользователя Mike за ответ. Вот готовое решение, может кому-то пригодиться...

```
.model small
.data    
HEXDIGIT   DB  "0123456789ABCDEF"
VAR1 DB 0110111b

.stack 256 
.code      
main:      
mov ax, @data  
mov ds, ax  
MOV  AL , VAR1
shr al,4

MOV  BX , OFFSET  HEXDIGIT

XLAT
MOV  DL , AL
MOV AH , 02H
INT  21H

XOR AL,AL
MOV  AL , VAR1
and al,0Fh

XLAT 
MOV Dl, AL
MOV AH , 02H
INT  21H

mov ax,4c00h
 int 21h    
 end main
```